# Unslider : how to trigger only on desktop?

Tags: jquery, slider, unslider

I'm using unslider and I would like it to trigger only on desktop, not on mobile devices. I'd like it to be destroyed when the window is resized. My code actually works but only on page refresh, the window resize part doesn't work.

Any idea ?

```
function triggerReportingSlider(){
    var ww = $(window).width();

    if (ww >= 992){
        var slider = $('.reporting-slider').unslider({arrows: false,
            autoplay: true, speed: 1000, delay: 5000});
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    triggerReportingSlider();
})

$(window).resize(function(){
    triggerReportingSlider();
})
```

Comment: There is a destroy method, `slider.unslider('destroy')`, but I wasn't able to get it working in a Codepen - it seems like it doesn't properly clean up after itself when you call destroy. Are you tied to this particular plugin? Most of the popular carousels support breakpoints out of the box (e.g. Owl, Slick, Swiper).

Comment: Yes, I already tried the destroy method without success. I like this plugin so if possible I would like to keep it. But of course if there is no solution I will switch.